# подключение нескольких слайдеров на странице

Tags: jquery

есть несколько слайдеров на странице, которые подключаются таким кодом с базовым набором опций, общим для всех слайдеров:

```
var swiperSlider = $('.swiper-container');
swiperSlider.each(function() {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(this, {
        loop: true,
        nextButton: $(this).parent().find('.swiper-button-next')[0],
        prevButton: $(this).parent().find('.swiper-button-prev')[0],
    })
});
```

некоторые слайдеры должны иметь кастомное оформление и элементы, вроде пагинации или показа определенного количества слайдов. если хранить данные об этих нужных доп.опциях в дата-атрибутах, например, то как их добавить в объекты при переборе?

Comment: var mydata = data('param') || 'default_value';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге нашлось такое решение:

```
var swiperSlider = $('.swiper-container');
swiperSlider.each(function() {
    var options = $(this).data('options') || {},
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        swiperDefaults = {
            loop: true,
            nextButton: $parent.find('.swiper-button-next')[0],
            prevButton: $parent.find('.swiper-button-prev')[0],
        };

    var swiperOptions = $.extend(swiperDefaults, options),
        mySwiper = new Swiper(this, swiperOptions);
});
```

Соответственно, объект с дополнительными опциями хранится в дата-атрибуте слайдера.

Answer (score 2):

На php можно вот так сделать:

Создаем файл incswiper.php (от слов "include swiper", но можно и с другим названием). В этом файле у нас будут "строительные блоки" для сборки разных вариантов Swiper.

```
   <?php
    function GetSwiper($pagename) // вариант с Pagination
    {
        echo '<div class="swiper-container">';
        GetSwiperContent1($pagename);
        GetSwiperPagination1($pagename);
        GetSwiperInit1($pagename);
        echo '</div>';
    }
   function GetSwiper2($pagename) // вариант без Pagination, например (можно компоновать разные варианты, составные части тоже можно добавить любые, пользуясь Swiper API).
    {
    echo '<div class="swiper-container">';
    GetSwiperContent2($pagename); // функцию с контентом для Swiper2 по аналогии с первой не составит труда составить, как и функцию инициализации и др.
    GetSwiperInit2($pagename);
    echo '</div>';
    }
   function GetSwiperContent1($pagename)
   {
    echo
    '<div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="ALT1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="ALT2">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="ALT3">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/img4" alt="ALT4">
            </a>
            </div>
    </div>';
 }
 function GetSwiperPagination1($pagename)
 {
    echo '<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>';
 }
 function GetSwiperInit1($pagename)
 {
    echo 
    '<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Swiper = new Swiper(\'.swiper-container\', {
            loop: true,
            speed: 1200,
            pagination: \'.swiper-pagination\',
            paginationClickable: true,
            effect: \'fade\', // Could be "slide", "fade", "cube", "coverflow" or "flip"
            autoplay: 6000,
            autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
        });
    </script>';
}
```

А дальше в файле, где будем подключать Swiper, пишем строку `include 'inc/incswiper.php';

И потом в нужном месте "выплёвываем" нужный вариант Swiper-а (Swiper1, 2, 3 ... n - собрать эти варианты можно как конструктор из кирпичиков). Вообще, здесь еще несколько "нюансов" есть (например, файл-обработчик и в нужном месте ввести переменную pagename), но я хотел не весь проект выложить, а предложить метод. Надеюсь, идея понятна!

Функции GetSwiper1 и GetSwiper2 - варианты сборки Swiper, а вот все остальные функции - "строительные блоки" для них. Вариантов Swiper можно собрать сколько угодно, при этом для каждого можно использовать свои "строительные блоки", но никто не запрещает использовать повторно одни и те же, в таком случае нужно придумать вменяемое пространство имен, иначе будет путаница.

Comment: "Выплёвываем", естественно, вот так: <?php function Example() {GetSwiper1(); echo 'какой-то код ...'; GetSwiper2; echo 'какой-то код ...'; и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать универсальный слайдер, с анимацией и оформлением. Закопипастить столько, сколько надо, присвоив уникальные ID, а потом кастомизировать.